# Computed properties in a PageModel

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a subclass of `PageModel` that looks like this:

```
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    ...

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        Comments = await _context.Comment.Where(comment => comment.LinkId == id).ToListAsync();

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

## Moving the code to the property definition

Instead of computing the property value inside `OnGetAsync`, I had considered having the computation code be at the property definition site:

```
    public IList<Comment> Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Comment.Where(comment => comment.LinkId == Link.Id).ToList();
        }
    }
```

One downside there is that the code is no longer async.

The code runs each time the property is called (which may or may not be desired).

## Putting the code in a method

Finally, I can put the code in a method instead of a property:

```
    public async Task<IList<Comment>> Comments()
    {
        return await _context.Comment.Where(comment => comment.LinkId == Link.Id).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Now it's async again. But we have a little syntactic overhead at the callsite:

```
await Comments()
```

I.e. we need to use `await` and the parens.

## Question

I like the second approach as the code is kept close to the property definition. This is especially nice when there are many properties. (It seems awkward to have a long list of property definitions only to set them up later in `OnGet`.) But as mentioned, there are a couple of potential downsides.

What is the idiomatic and recommended way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the [.NET guidelines for property design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property), there are some relevant bits:

> AVOID throwing exceptions from property getters

and

> Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any
> preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably
> be redesigned to be a method.

Generally properties should be simple and performant, otherwise a method is a better choice. Using a method also gives you control over exactly when it is invoked, which is more difficult with properties that execute on access.

In this case, it would be ideal to keep any queries etc in the `OnGetAsync` where you and others expect to find it, and certainly to keep it on an `async` path.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Noah!